# Why my webpack yelling about a big size of configuration?

Tags: webpack

I collect Web application, that's the result of my Assembly, it S all very, very simple

src/js/1.index.js    529 KiB       1  [emitted]  [big]  vendors~lodash

Why I get a conspicuous file about the size of the file, there's nothing else?

WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets: 
  src/js/1.index.js (529 KiB)

Comment: It's not just one index.js and lodash but also many other libraries. Add the webpack plugin [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer) and you will know what is being contracted.
I also need to loadash not add everything but only what is needed `import { map, tail, times, uniq } from 'lodash';` Add lazy libraries and divide bundel into chunks more here [code-splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/)